# working with hash keys and values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a model QuizAttempt that is going to check the result of a Quiz. I am looking to loop through each submitted answer and check the question id, if the answer supplied is correct. I'm looking for some guidance please...

```
class QuizAttempt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quiz

  validates_presence_of :quiz, :user
  validate :check_result

  attr_accessor :questions, :submitted_answers

  private

  def self.create_for_user_and_answers!(user, answers)
    self.new(:user => user).tap do |q| 
      q.submitted_answers = answers
      q.questions = []
      answers.each{|k, v| q.questions = q.questions << Question.find(k.gsub(/[^0-9]/i, '').to_i) }
    end
  end

  def check_result
    if submitted_answers
      unless submitted_answers.keys.length == quiz.easy_questions + quiz.moderate_questions + quiz.hard_questions
        self.errors.add(:submitted_answers, "must be provided for each question")
      end
    else
      self.errors.add(:submitted_answers, "must be provided")
    end

    return false unless self.errors.empty?

    score = 0
    submitted_answers.each do |answer|
      #check the answers and score + 1 if correct
    end
    self.total_questions = submitted_answers.length
    self.passed_questions = score
    self.passed = percentage_score >= quiz.pass_percentage
  end

  public

  def percentage_score
    (passed_questions / total_questions.to_f * 100).to_i
  end

end
```

The submitted answers are in the form of a (nested?) hash, returned from a form with radio buttons

```
{"question_1"=>{"answer_3"=>"5"}, "question_2"=>{"answer_2"=>"4"}}
```

But when I loop through them as in the above QuizAttempt model ie. submitted_answers.each do |answer| i get answer ==

```
["question_1", {"answer_3"=>"5"}]
```

And I want to check these answers based on the question model below

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz

  validates :question, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 254}
  validates :answer_1, :answer_2, :answer_3, :answer_4, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 254}
  validates :rank, :presence => true, :numericality => { :only_integer => true, :greater_than => 0, :less_than => 4 }
  validate :only_one_answer_correct  

  #has boolean values answer_1_correct, answer_2_correct, answer_3_correct, answer_4_correct

  def correct_answer_number
    (1..4).each{|i| return i if send("answer_#{i}_correct")}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be much simpler if you changed the way the form was structured, however.

```
answer[1].keys.first.sub("answer_", '').to_i
```

will give you 3 given your example ["question_1", {"answer_3"=>"5"}] which you can then compare to correct_answer_number in the Question model.

I'm unsure what the value associated with the "answer_x" is? I presumed it wasn't the answer (as in 1,2,3 or 4) as it's 5 and you only have 4 possible answers, so I presumed that 5 was the actual answer to the question and ignored it.